# JavaScript .replace() function with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have the following code:

```
my_string.replace(/^\[poll:([^\]]+)\]/mgi, function(match, capture) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/my_url,
        data: {
            text: match
        },
        success: function(response) {
            return response;
        }
    });
});
```

I am doing an AJAX call in the anonymous function which returns the content that I would like to replace the string with but it is not working. It appears that I am returning the AJAX function rather than the response content.

Comment: you can't do that because ajax is asynchronous!!! the `$.ajax()` returns a promise object, not the response of the ajax request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first A in AJAX stands for Asynchronous. `$.ajax` does not return data synchronously like that.